# Why multiple nextInt() works?

Tags: java

In the following Java code

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    //Cmd1
int i1,i2;                                 //Cmd2
i1 = input.nextInt();                      //Cmd3
System.out.println("value of i1 is "+ i1); //Cmd4
i2 = input.nextInt();                      //Cmd5
System.out.println("value of i2 is "+ i2); //Cmd6
String s1;                                 //Cmd7
input.nextLine();                          //Cmd8
s1 = input.nextLine();                     //Cmd9
System.out.println("value of s1 is "+ s1); //Cmd10
```

I got the following output in my console

```
<myinput> 1
<output>  value of i1 is 1
<myinput> 2
<output>  value of i2 is 2
<myinput> firstString
<output>  value of s1 is firstString
```

<myinput> kept on waiting for input till i pressed `enter` key. I tried `tab`, multiple `tab`, `space` but it kept on waiting and didn't move to the next command which is <output> hence i assumed that nextInt waits till it find \n in an input stream before moving onto next command.

Looking at the answers from [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo), the reason we have to add `Cmd8` is because nextInt() keep on reading input till `\n`, sends input to program and puts `\n` back in front of input stream. Now when nextLine() in "Cmd8" starts reading it, it finds `\n` at the starting of input stream without any preceding string, it assumes user didn't enter anything hence takes empty string as input and go to `Cmd9`. 
 My doubt here is since nextInt() also reads till `\n` (implying from my experience that `Cmd3` kept on waiting until i pressed `enter`) why is `Cmd5` waiting for my input. It should have also find `\n` in the beginning of input stream and assume that i didn't enter anything and take empty integer as input (similar to how `Cmd8` is behaving). What is happening here?

Comment: What makes you believe `nextInt()` stops at `\n`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the EXACT sequence of keyboard keys you have pressed while running this program. Also include the output you get from your application.

Comment: @GarvitArora The line you are entering is "send" to your java application when you pressed `enter`, not before. So when you entering digits for your number these input isn't send to your java application yet, so you java application is still waiting for your first input.

Comment: @Progman Sorry can you please elaborate. What i understood from your comment is when i press "enter" it "send" my input to program and also creates \n character which is not consumed. But nextInt stops reading at "send" command rather than \n. So the input for nextInt(i2), is technically `\n + <valueEntered>` till "send" , but since it skips whitespaces it only stores <valueEntered>. Is this correct understanding?

Comment: @GarvitArora What is the question/problem/issue you have? It's difficult to understand what you are trying to ask. Please [edit] your post to add a detailed description of what you are asking.

Comment: Check the implementations of `nextInt()` and `next()` methods in jdk sources:  https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have analyzed your question with debugging JRE Scanner class methods. When you called `nextInt` function, Scanner looks current buffer. If there is no available input, started listening to the keyboard until you press `Enter` key, whole keyboard characters appended to the buffer and tried to match that it is an integer or not. When it is found an integer `nextInt` returns the value and increments the buffer's position index. Next step, you called the `nextInt` again, and there is only `\n` character, then it is discarded and waited for the next integer pattern. Also, the buffer's next character is `\n` again. When you called `nextLine` it looks to the buffer and prints an empty line. So second `nextLine` is starting with empty text.

Maybe it can be confusing. Let's look at the scenario:

**Note:** Index `^` represents the buffer's reading position.

---

1. Step

```java
i1 = input.nextInt();
```

```
keyboard = 1 2 {Enter}
buffer = | 1 | 2 | \n |
index  =   ^
```

returns `12` and the  next buffer position is located to `\n`

---

2. Step

```java
i2 = input.nextInt();
```

```
keyboard = 3 4 {Enter}
buffer = | 1 | 2 | \n | 3 | 4 | \n |
index  =           ^
```

returns `34` and the next buffer position is located to second `\n`

---

3. Step

```java
input.nextLine();
```

Buffer has `\n` character, so Scanner does not wait for keyboard and returns the value.

```
buffer = | 1 | 2 | \n | 3 | 4 | \n |
index  =                         ^
```

returns `empty text`

---

4. Step

```java
s1 = input.nextLine();
```

```
keyboard = test {Enter}
buffer = | 1 | 2 | \n | 3 | 4 | \n | t | e | s | t | \n |
index  =                             ^
```

returns `test`

---

Answer (score 3):

Note the following excerpt from [`Scanner#next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) documentation:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
> complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
> delimiter pattern.

The default delimiter use by `Scanner` is `\p{javaWhitespace}+` which you can get as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(input.delimiter());
    }
}
```

The following lines of code show how a complete token is found as soon as `10` or `hello` is found i.e. no matter how many times you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `next()`, `nextInt()` etc. will keep asking for the input until a non-whitespace character is entered.  **Note**: In case of `nextInt()`, the value `10` is parseable to `int` but `hello` is not and therefore `InputMismatchException` will be thrown.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(Character.isWhitespace('\n'));
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n".split("\\p{javaWhitespace}+").length);
        System.out.println("10\n".split("\\p{javaWhitespace}+").length);
        System.out.println("hello\n".split("\\p{javaWhitespace}+").length);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
0
1
1
```

This is applicable to all `nextXXX()` except `nextLine()` whose [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) (excerpt given below) is quite clear how it behaves different from other `nextXXX()`.

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
> was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
> excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
> beginning of the next line. Since this method continues to search
> through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of
> the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are
> present.

In other words, `nextLine()` will catch everything including the whitespace character entered directly or leftover from the previous input.